# Java Graphics g.drawString

Tags: java

Here I have two methods, one which generates a list based on instances and the other which uses drawString() to display some text...

```
private Map<String, Color> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();


for (int u = 0; u < people.size(); u++) {
                if (people.get(u) instanceof Boy) {
                     list[u]="B";
                     hashMapMap.put(list[u], Color.red);
                    System.out.print("B");
                } else if (people.get(u) instanceof Girl) {
                    System.out.print("G");
                    list[e] = "G";
                    hashMap.put(list[u], Color.green);

                }
            }
```

So this gives me two arrays, respectively called 'list' and 'hashMap'.

So the contents of my arrays are now
            list[B,G,B,G] and hashMap provides the values and keys for these values in the list array respectively. I am using the code below but its not working. My question is: how do I colour each value based on their key from the hashmap list?

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.drawString(list, 10, 10)
            // will like to colour each value according to its key in the hashMap list
            }
```

Comment: You say you have two arrays called list and hasMap. `hashMap` is a map, not an array. Your code also uses `hashMapMap`, which is not declared. `list` is undeclared, and appears to be an array, but you're passing it to `g.drawString` as if it is a string. In any case, if you want to draw a string in colour, you should call `g.setColor(...)`, which you don't seem to be doing anywhere.

Comment: You could iterate over the HashMap: for every value call `g.setColor(...)` as @khelwood suggested, followed by `g.drawstring(theKey, ..., ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following code:

```
public class MyClass extends JComponent {
    HashMap<String, Color> map = new HashMap<>();
    private static final String BOY = "B";
    private static final String GIRL = "G";

    public MyClass() {
        String[] peopleArray = new String[people.size()];
        map.put(BOY, Color.RED);
        map.put(GIRL, Color.GREEN);
        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
            if (people.get(i) instanceof Boy) {
            peopleArray[i] = BOY;
            System.out.print(BOY);
        } else if (people.get(i) instanceof Girl) {
            peopleArray[i] = GIRL;
            System.out.print(GIRL);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //you might need a for-loop or smth here. I'll just draw a boy in this example.
        g.setColor(map.get(BOY));
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        g.drawString(BOY, x, y);
    }
}
```

Tips:

- try using better formatted code (and correct code, especially) next time. While I didn't dislike your question, others apparently did, and that will save you from dislikes ;) (not to mention raising the chance of getting a useful answer)
- if you repeatedly use the same string (or any primitive variable, maybe even objects, for that matter), make it a constant (as I did in the example above with `BOY` and `GIRL`)
- in general, it's better to use `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, since `paint` also paints the border etc., which you usually don't want - you just need the components.

Comment: The first line of a paintComponent method should *always* be `super.paintComponent(g);`.

Comment: How could you call `super.paintComponent(g);` when your class doesn't extend a Swing component?

Comment: @Thibstars i guess i can't. the guy that asked the question used "paint(Graphics g)", though, and because I didn't write the code in an IDE, I might have might some minor mistakes here ^^